# captureVisibleTab in chrome extension returns a double sized image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I'm developing a screenshot taking google chrome extension. But my problem is, that the screenshot don't have the original size, it is much bigger. If the size of my web document has 1272x594 pixel, the screenshot will be 2544x1188 pixel.

The minimal working example takes a screenshot of the current tab, after clicking on "Test Plugin" in context menu and displays the screenshot in the current tab as an overlay.

My minimal working example:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Minimal working Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs", "activeTab"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: 'minimalExampe',
        title: 'Test Plugin',
        contexts: ['all']
    });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(itemData) {
    if (itemData.menuItemId == "minimalExampe") {
        console.log('clicked');
        // checks, if content.js is already injected, otherwise content.js is added
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {func: 'alreadyInjected'}, function (response) {
                if (response === undefined) {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                        file: 'content.js'
                    });
                    console.log('Script added');
                } else {
                    console.log('Script was already injected');
                }
                //does the screenshot
                chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {format: 'png'}, function (screen) {
                    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {func: 'showPicture', picture: screen});
                    });

                });

            });
        });
    }
});
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch(request.func) {
            case 'showPicture':
                showPicture(request.picture);
                break;
            case 'alreadyInjected':
                sendResponse({alreadyInjected: true});
                break;
        }
    });

function showPicture(picture) {
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
    console.log(window.innerHeight);
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = picture;
    img.style.zIndex = '1000';
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    img.style.top = '0';
    img.style.left = '0';
    img.onload = function () {
        console.log(img.naturalWidth);
        console.log(img.naturalHeight);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Does anybody know why? Every help is welcome. I already searched on Stackoverflow, but there is only one same question with no answer because no minimal working example or anything else was provided.

Best,
Klaus

Comment: Sounds like either a bug in Chrome or maybe a feature - if your OS is configured for HiDPI. I think you can file an issue on https://crbug.com - describe the steps to reproduce the bug and attach your demo extension in a zip file.

Comment: Thanks ´for help wOxxOm. But if it would be a bug, wouldn't have other extensions the same problem? I installed the extension Explain & Send Screenshot and there i get the picture in normal size.

Comment: Ok, I tested a little bit and it seems to work, if I lower the display scaling in Windows 10 to 100%. Default is 200% on my computer. Have filled a bug report. Thanks